# Етимологія слова "скрипта"?

Tags: етимологія

Серед рідкісних слів у творах Франка побачив слово "[скрипта](http://www.i-franko.name/uk/Studies/RareWords/S.html)" (якого не знайшов в СУМі):

> **Скрипта** – підземна печера

Тому вирішив перевірити його етимологію, однак пошуки в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf) та в Інтернеті не дали ніяких результатів.

Comment: Один із подібних переліків слів [посилається](//zbruc.eu/node/26113) на [25-й том зібрання творів Франка в 50 томах](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Franko/Zibrannia_tvoriv_u_50_tomakh_t25/) (також [1](//books.google.com/books?id=w7kGAQAAIAAJ), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=UknnAAAAMAAJ), [3](//books.google.com/books?id=Bl5gAAAAMAAJ)) — й дійсно там на с. 556 написано «скри́пта — підземна печера», — але конкретний твір, де Франко вживав це слово в цьому значенні, я не знайшов.

Comment: Так, теж намагався знайти це слово у його творах, але нічого не вийшло. Гадаєте, він його ніколи не використовував?

Comment: Та ні, я вірю, що використовував, просто хотілося б знайти контекст (але, на жаль, пошук у DJVU-файлі не працює, а в Google Книгах працює неідеально).

Comment: А це не опечатка? Може, малося на увазі "крипта"?

Comment: Напевно ні, бо "крипта" не зовсім рідкісне слово, але гадаю, що можливо між цими словами може бути щось спільне.